# Calling function with typed parameter from outside module

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a Powershell module ExportHelper.psm1 in which I define a custom class `Text` and a function `Add-Text`:

```
class Text {
  [string]$value
  [Format]$format
}

function Add-Text {
  Param([Text]$text)
  echo $text.value
}
```

It is important to me that the `Add-Text` function takes a parameter of type `Text` as I want to use specific properties of this class and it wouldn't be appropriate for someone to call the function with a string parameter.

If I call the `Add-Text` function from within ExportHelper.psm1 then I see the expected result:

```
$testText = [Text]@{
    value = "Test text"
    format = ([Format]::Heading1)
}
Add-Text -text $testText

Outputs:
Test text
```

If I call the `Add-Text` function from a separate powershell script Playings.ps1 with exactly the same `$testText` variable constructed in exactly the same way, I instead get an error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'text'. Cannot convert the "Text" value of type "Text" to type "Text".

If I try `echo $testText.GetType().Name` then I see `$testText` is correctly created as a `Text` object.

I always `Import-Module` and `Remove-Module` at each end of my script to make sure I'm using the latest version of ExportHelper.psm1 and indeed I see changes if I modify the `Add-Text` function.

So my question is: why does Powershell not understand that the `$testText` variable defined in Playings.ps1 is already of the same type as required by `Add-Text`?  Why does this error only occur when calling the function from outside the module?

Comment: Shouldn't the type be string and not the class TEXT.

Comment: What is `[Format]` ?

Comment: Text and Format are two custom classes I have defined within ExportHelper.psm1